# Flutter: response variable blank in http request

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am trying to create a profile page for my flutter app
Here is a snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MyProfile extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _MyProfileState createState() => _MyProfileState();
}

class _MyProfileState extends State<MyProfile> {
  bool visible=false;
  var postData=List();
  var jsonData;
  Future accountInfo()async{
    
    var url ='http://192.168.0.107/get_account.php';
    var response= await http.get(url);
    var jsonData= json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() { 
      postData=jsonData;
    });
    debugPrint(jsonData);
    return jsonData;
    }
    
    @override
    void initState(){
      super.initState();
      accountInfo();
    }
```

However, the variables postData and jsonData are returned as null.
Value of postData=[]

The API is working perfectly, tried it with postman and also tried intercepting with a proxy tool.
I am getting a valid json response body. But the values are not passed onto jsonData or postData.

When I use postData inside a text widget i get this error:-
RangeError(index): Index out of Range: no indices are valid: 0

Comment: is response null as well? and response.body respectively?

Comment: no response.body is clearly returning the desired json. Have verified it using proxy too

Comment: response.body is not null, however when debugging for value of jsonData I get the following error  ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define jsonData as

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData= jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined two jsonData. That may be the reason. Also, set jsonData inside setState(), too. Try this:

```
var jsonData;
Future accountInfo()async{
  setState(() {
    visible=true;
  });
  var url ='http://192.168.0.107/get_account.php';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  
  setState(() { 
    jsonData = json.decode(response.body); // Here we changed!
    postData = jsonData;
  });
```

Comment: Tried this, still getting RangeError